# How to inject hilt viewModel to be used with fresh state in multiple navgraphs

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-hilt

The Problem:
I have a parent fragment that creates 1-4 splites of a single navgraph (split screen of a tablet). I have a global ViewModel, which I want to be able to only be shared in one of the pieces. so each split have a global viewModel

If I use `@InstallIn(ActivityRetainedComponent::class)` together with

```
@Provides
@ActivityRetainedScoped
```

I get one ViewModel shared between the pieces. See picture

If I remove `@ActivityRetainedScoped`  Every fragment gets its own ViewModel. See picture

What I want:

Each piece creates its own parent ViewModel. See picture with green activity

I’ve only figured out 2 different ugly solutions. that might work:

- Create the ViewModels in the parent fragment. and pass it in some way.
- When talking to the global parent pass the index of the piece

Ps. Not in the picture. Connected to each fragment there is a fragmentViewModel. and those fragments talks to the global ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a nested Graph.

```
 private val viewModel: NameOfYourViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nameOfYourFragment)
```